# throw statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, exception

in Kotlin expressions like

```
fun main() {
    throw throw throw RuntimeException("boom")
}
```

or

```
fun main() {
    throw throw return
}
```

are syntactically correct

I understand ideas behind it, but I wonder why there is no Warn (at least in Itellij) when writing such nonsense.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/293819#293819

Comment: Is it nonsense though? `throw throw return` *returns*, and `throw throw throw RuntimeException("boom")` throws a runtime exception. There's nothing unexpected to warn about. You can warn about the redundant word `throw`, but one could argue that lots of other redundant things are not warned, so why should this one be?

Comment: @Sweeper unreachable code is often warned about. I find it equally valid to expect a warning in `throw throw RuntimeException("boom")` and in `throw error("boom")`, so why would they yield different results?

Comment: @Sweeper it is redundant code that is pretty easy to catch via static analysis. But somehow it is not there. Thus I wonder mb there is a deeper intention here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is reported as a minor problem in [KT-22621 "throw throw Exception()": False negative UNREACHABLE_CODE warning](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22621). It should be noted that unreachable code is warned if you put parentheses:

```
throw (throw Exception())
// or
throw (return)
```

Also, `return throws Exception()` gives the warning too.

Unfortunately, it is still an open issue after 4 years.

After reading Kotlin's source code for a bit, I think this is unintentional. Let's consider ControlFlowProcessor.kt, [`visitThrowExpression`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/cfg/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cfg/ControlFlowProcessor.kt#L1248):

```
override fun visitThrowExpression(expression: KtThrowExpression) {
    mark(expression)

    generateJumpsToCatchAndFinally()

    val thrownExpression = expression.thrownExpression ?: return
    generateInstructions(thrownExpression)

    val thrownValue = builder.getBoundValue(thrownExpression) ?: return
    builder.throwException(expression, thrownValue)
}
```

Consider `throw throw Exception()`. When the first `throw` is visited, `generateInstructions(thrownExpression)` generates the part of the CFG that corresponds to `throw Exception()`. This causes the second `throw` to be visited, generating the correct CFG for `throw Exception()`.

The problem comes, when `builder.getValue(thrownExpression)` gets called. This gets a `PseudoValue` from the CFG builder that represents the thrown value. However, (I suspect that) this returns nil and `builder.throwException` is not called. This is because when building the CFG for `throw Exception()`, no value is bound. Compare this to what happens in [`visitParenthesizedExpression`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/cfg/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cfg/ControlFlowProcessor.kt#L245), or `visitCallExpression`, but you'd need to trace deeper.

This doesn't affect control flow analysis too much, since the part of the CFG generated for `throw Exception()` is correct. The CFG *does* end up missing a node to represent the outer `throw` though, which is what [`builder.throwException`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/cfg/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cfg/pseudocode/ControlFlowInstructionsGenerator.kt#L326) would have added. This node would have been marked as unreachable and a warning been issued, but this node doesn't even exist, so no warnings.